# Deserialization does not occur

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I try to use passport.js to auth on my app (I use passport.js with REST API and without some redirects on the backend). But deserialization does not occur. Help me, please. This is my code:
It's serialization and deserialization.

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log('serializeUser: ', user);
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    console.log('deserializeUser: ', id);
    User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

My middleware:

```
app.use(
    expressSession({
        secret: 'top_secret',
        store: new FileStore(),
        cookie: {
            path: '/',
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
        },
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
    })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

My strategy:

```
const signIn = (passport) => {
    passport.use(
        'signin',
        new LocalStrategy(
            {
                usernameField: 'email',
                passwordField: 'password',
            },
            (email, password, done) => {
                User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
                    if (err) return done(err);

                    if (!user) {
                        return done(null);
                    }

                    if (!isValidPassword(user, password)) {
                        return done(null);
                    }

                    return done(null, user);
                });
            }
        )
    );
};
```

My controller:

```
const handleSignIn = (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('signin', (err, user) => {
        if (err) return next(err);

        if (user) {
            req.logIn(user, (err) => {
                if (err) return next(err);

                res.send(req.user);
            });
        } else {
            res.status(HttpStatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED).send({ error: 'error with login or password' });
        }
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

After authtorization, I try to get data from endpoint and there I check req.session.passport but it is undefined

```
    const handleGetUserData = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.passport); // undefined

    try {
        const data = await Users.getUser();
        res.status(HttpStatusCode.OK).send(data);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(HttpStatusCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send({ error });
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have access to passport data in `req.user`?

Comment: Yes, I have access